# Including Rails engine tests with autotest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest

Just wondered if anyone knew of a great way to include rails engine tests into autotest? Basically when I run autotest, I would like to have all of my app tests run first, then have the tests run in my engine.  I noticed this gist after some googling: [Autotest for Engines](https://gist.github.com/61104) Seems kind of like a lot to have to go through - wondered if there was something simpler I was totally missing.

Comment: did you figure this out?  I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, so that works but you don't want to use it?

If you're worried about having it clog up your .autotest you could name it something else:

Save it as vendor/autotest/autotest_engines.rb

Then from within your .autotest:

`require 'vendor/autotest/autotest_engines'`

---

P.S. It's not really that big compared to the autotest/rails gem, and you're probably requiring that too:
https://github.com/grosser/autotest-rails/blob/master/lib/autotest/rails.rb